# SQL FOR JSON Conversion Trouble

Tags: sql, json, type-conversion

I'm trying to run the following query, to build a JSON string from a customer record in a sample database.

```
SELECT
    CustomerID, 
    CustomerName,
    PersonID AS [CustomerContact.PersonID],
    SUBSTRING(FullName, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName)) AS [CustomerContact.FirstName],
    SUBSTRING(FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) + 1, LEN(FullName)) AS [CustomerContact.LastName],
    EmailAddress AS [CustomerContact.Email],
    DeliveryAddressLine1 AS [CustomerContact.Address1],
    DeliveryAddressLine2 AS [CustomerContact.Address2],
    CityName AS [CustomerContact.City],
    StateProvinceName AS [CustomerContact.State],
    DeliveryPostalCode AS [CustomerContact.Zip],
    CustomerCategoryName AS CustomerType,
    WebsiteURL As Website
FROM
    Sales.Customers
    LEFT JOIN Sales.CustomerCategories 
    ON Customers.CustomerCategoryID = CustomerCategories.CustomerCategoryID
    LEFT JOIN Application.Cities
    ON Customers.DeliveryCityID = Cities.CityID
    LEFT JOIN Application.StateProvinces
    ON Cities.StateProvinceID = StateProvinces.StateProvinceCode
    LEFT JOIN Application.People
    ON Customers.CustomerID = People.PersonID
WHERE
    Customers.CustomerID = 200
FOR JSON PATH
```

When I try this, it just throws the following error:

```
Conversion failed when converting the ****** value '******' to data type ******.
```

Does anyone know what this means?

EDIT: The ***'s are literally showing as asterisks, not a hidden value.  The line error is `Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1`

Comment: In this case it probably means you are trying to equate two columns with different types. Could you share what the *****'s are and if it gives you a line number?

Comment: The first thing that springs to mind is this line: ON Cities.StateProvinceID = StateProvinces.StateProvinceCode - did you mean to join ID with Code?

Comment: That actually fixed it, it generated the JSON String, but it's...funky.  Not what I expected.

Comment: @Simon That worked for me, if you wanna make it an official answer, I can mark you as the one that solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that springs to mind is this line:

```
ON Cities.StateProvinceID = StateProvinces.StateProvinceCode
```

Did you mean to join ID with Code?